# Get Max(X) value from ACCDB using vbscript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I would like to know how should get Maximum value of a specific column using VBScript. Here is where I got to so far:

```
Function GetTrnID(Database, TableName)

    Set oRecordSetTrn = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set oConnTrn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


    oConnTrn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = "& Database &""
    Wscript.echo ("Select MAX(ID)  from "& TableName &"")
    Set oRecordSetTrn = oConnTrn.Execute("Select MAX(ID)  from "& TableName &"") 

    Set TrnID = oRecordSetTrn

    Wscript.echo "ID: "+ TrnID +""
    GetTrnId = TrnID


End Function
```

When I am Getting error when i try to Echo the value using:

```
Wscript.echo "ID: "+ TrnID +""
```

It says Type Mismatch. And if I just remove the echo, the variable that calls for this function gives an error as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `MAX(ID)` should be in the first field (`Fields(0)`) of the recordset.

And use a simple assignment ... `TrnID =` instead of `Set TrnID =`

Use the concatenation operator (`&`) instead of `+` when you create the string expression to give to the last `Wscript.echo`

```vb
Set oRecordSetTrn = oConnTrn.Execute("Select MAX(ID) from " & TableName) 

TrnID = oRecordSetTrn.Fields(0).Value

Wscript.echo "ID: " & TrnID
```

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly. But What exactly means oRecordSetTrn.Fields(0).Value? I must understand...

Comment: `oRecordSetTrn` is your recordset object variable.  `.Fields(0)` is the first field in the current row of that recordset. (`Fields()` numbering is zero-based.)  And `.Value` is the value of that field.

Comment: Okay so i think my knowledge on the recordset itself was not right. I am starting in VBscript so... If i understand well, the "RecordSet" itself is a bit like an array of value, right?

Comment: I think of it as more like a query result set or a table in Datasheet View ... rows and columns.  It would be easier to learn recordset details by experimenting with VBA inside Access.  Later, you can take what you've learned there and translate it to VBScript as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations!